# Is my AMD Radeon graphics working properly?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon, intel-graphics

I recently purchased a HP Laptop which has 2 GB AMD Radeon 8670M Graphics card. Rest of the specs would be Core i3, 4GB DDR3 RAM etc.

I have one or two CAD applications, one being DraftSight(free alternative to AutoCAD, and lighter too). This is a 300Mb 2D drafting package, for creating building plans. It is not as graphics intensive as say, photoshop or 3DSMAx.

All in all, my specs would be more than enough for running this one smoothly. However I notice after some time, the cursor starts moving in a jarring fashion, not smooth. It sometimes creates difficulties in snapping to points.

I snooped around and i can see both Intel Graphics options, as well as AMD Graphics options, on right click. In device manager, under the head of Display Adapters, there are again 2 entries - Intel HD Graphics Family, and AMD Radeon HD 8670, both with their drivers and running properly.

Is this expected? Are both drivers and adapters expected to be present simultaneously?  I remember in my old PC days, when i brought my own graphics card, i simply remove the Intel GMA Graphics accelerator..

CAn this result in the above performance problem?

Comment: Are you sure AMD Enduro is configured correctly?

Comment: Which Model of HP Laptop is it? could be that it isn't switching between the integrated or dedicated - another point would be are you able to get more Memory into it because CAD applications can be quite intensive

Comment: Model HP-15 n259-TX. i can purchase more memory, but i really thought draftsight is for 2D drafting, so this much should be enough, it is much more than the recommended settings.

Comment: How do i find out if it is switching or not switching!?